# Asynchronous call from list item of recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` (`ListView`). Each of the list item (row), has upload / download button. When the user press the button, it has to upload or download the file to and from Amazon.

The upload or download process is being done using `Kotlin Fuel` framework. Fuel is a Asynchronous framework. I wrote a callback to come to `RecyclerView` adapter once the upload or download process is completed.

Now, I have to change the button (ex. If the button is upload, after the user click, it has to upload and once the upload completes, it should change it to download button). I search the list (that I pass to form list view) to find the position of the list item in the `RecyclerView` once the call back method is called.

But I don't know how to get hold of the `View Holder` to update the button from upload to download or download to upload. I tried, to call `notifyDataSetChanged` once I identify the row. But it behaves so differently, that for the first page of the `RecyclerView`. It does not display upload / download button at all after the `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Should I call `notifyItemChanged(position)` so that it calls `bindViewHolder()` which has the logic to display download button if file does not exist otherwise upload button.

Or Is there any other better way to do it. I defined FUEL calls in separate file to enable re-usability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to access the `ViewHolder` directly.

`RecyclerView` uses a flyweight pattern that reuses Views for its visible items (as opposed to creating a View for every item in the adapter which would perform poorly and waste memory.)

Instead, manipulate your model as appropriate for the download state you are in, and then call `notifyItemChanged(position)` which in turn will cause your `RecyclerView` to call `onBindViewHolder` to update the item on your behalf.

You'll just need to make sure that your `onBindViewHolder` method has logic in it to look for the download state in your model to know what to do.